# Processing: function rotate doesn't work properly

Tags: processing

Hello i'm trying to draw a square in processing using only line() and rotate() functions but i'm having a bit of an issue probably with the rotate function.
Here is my code for the draw function:

```java
void draw(){
   background(0);
   stroke(255);
   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
       line(0, 0, GRID_SIZE, 0);
       translate(GRID_SIZE, 0);
       rotate(HALF_PI);
   }
}
```

The result:

[image: The result]

Why the bottom and the left lines are tilted even if i rotated by PI/2?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much expected behavior.

Keep in mind that in "real life", numbers like PI and PI/2 are infinitely long. Computers can't hold infinitely long numbers, so the variable `HALF_PI` holds an approximate value. So when you rotate by `HALF_PI`, you're actually rotating with a little bit of "error" each time. That error adds up, so you get artifacts like what you're seeing.

This is made worse by the fact that pixels are whole numbers, not `float` values. So if you have one pixel with a Y position of `20.0000001`, and another pixel with a Y position of `19.9999999`, they'll be rendered at `20` and `19` respectively, so you'll see a "big" difference (of 1 whole pixel) between them even though the real difference is small.

If you want your lines to look more square, then just use the `rect()` function that Processing provides.

Comment: Thanks mate i didn't think about that at all! Actually I'm drawing a square that way because i don't know if i have to draw every side and so because i didn't want to call `line()` four times i thought of that algorithm. Thanks for the explanation anyway!

Comment: @EnricoMarconi The code you posted does call `line()` four times. It sounds like just calling `line()` without any rotations is exactly what you should do.